# Is there a way to watch an http session to log the timout?

Tags: java, session, servlets, timeout

I have a simple Http servlet session which has a timeout of 1 minute for testing purposes. After refreshing the browser after a minute I need to login again so that works. But how do I keep track of the session so I can log the time it timed out without having to refresh the browser?

I googled a lot but I can simply just not find a solution.

Used `httpServletRequest.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60);` to set the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a class that implements `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` and add it to your web application as a listener (in `web.xml` or by an annotation).  There are a lot of tutorials out there that show the details.